# Complex Analysis - Derivation of Bode Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, contour-integration, control-theory

I am trying to work through the steps deriving the Bode Integral in the following paper:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405896315025045

I am stuck on page 261, left column, on the section for the Gamma_pk contour integral, specifically the following unjustified statement:

$$ S(s)=S'(s)(p_{k}-s)$$

S(s) is the sensitivity transfer function.  Pk is a pole of the open-loop transfer function, and therefore a zero of S(s), which the contour was chosen to go around.  Please see figure 3 in the paper for a visual depiction.

Anyhow, I think it's just the complex plane throwing me off here, but I am unable to arrive at, or justify, that statement.  I come close, but can't quite get all the way there.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: The closest I'm seeing right now is that $\displaystyle \frac{S'(s)}{S(s)}=\frac{d}{ds}\log S(s)=\frac{1}{p_k-s}.$ But it's not obvious to me why that should be true in general. (Also, should it be $p_k-s$ or $s-p_k$?)

Comment: Agreed, it's not obvious to me, either.  In fact, it leaves me highly doubting it could be true, in general.  According to paper, it is indeed $$ (p_{k} -s) $$

Comment: Where do you see that? The closest I see is the claim $\ln S(s)=\ln(s-p_k)+\ln S'(s)$, which still seems dubious but corresponds to $S(s)=(s-p_k)S'(s)$.

Comment: I am in the section above there. The one for $ \Gamma_{p_{k}} $

Third sentence in that section contains the statement from my OP. 

By the way, how do you keep your latex inline with the sentence it is contained in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful to consider one of the examples provided in the paper, namely that of an open-loop unstable system with sensitivity function $S(s)=\dfrac{s^2-1}{s^2+s+9}$. Then $$\frac{S'(s)}{S(s)}=\frac{d}{ds}\ln S(s)=\frac{2s}{s^2-1}-\frac{2s+1}{s^2+s+9}=\frac{s^2+20s+1}{(s^2-1)(s^2+s+9)}$$

or $$S(s)=S'(s)\cdot \frac{(s^2-1)(s^2+s+9)}{s^2+20s+1}.$$

It should be evident that this doesn't agree with their stated formula. That said, the reason $S(s)$ is open-loop unstable is due to the zero at $s=1$, and with this in mind we write $S(s)=S'(s)(s-1)\cdot f(s)$ where $$f(s)=\frac{(s+1)(s^2+s+9)}{s^2+20s+1}$$ is analytic in the right half-plane. This form seems entirely sufficient for the purposes of their argument.

Moreover, if we look to [Lewis's notes on control theory](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Ebahman/mthe332/course-notes.pdf) (which your paper cites!) then the above is a case of their first equation on page 366: Given a zero of $S_L(s)$ at $s=p_j$ with positive real part, one may write

$$\ln\frac{S_L(s)}{S_L(\infty)}=\ln(s-p_j)+\ln f_j(s)$$
with $f_j(s)$ being analytic on and within the contour which runs around $p_j$. So I would discount the paper's arguments for the Bode integral formula in favor of those in Lewis's notes.

Comment: Thank you!  This was super helpful and makes a lot of sense.  Also, I appreciate the extra reference (Lewis) for one more (rather detailed) derivation.  Cheers!

Comment: @EthanT Well, they did reference Lewis explicitly. Checking references is a good habit to pick up, at least when you find their treatment confusing.

Comment: Oh, I am buried in references right now, so its easy to miss one!